# Dont Consider Example text as value of textbox

Tags: jquery, magento-1.7

I want to show example text in Email text-box so I used code:-

```
<input name="login[username]" 
       onfocus="if (this.value == 'john@gmail.com') {this.value = ''; }" 
       onblur="if (this.value == ''){this.value = 'john@gmail.com'; }" 
       value="john@gmail.com"  
       id="email" 
       type="text" 
       class="input-text required-entry" 
       title="<?php echo $this->__('Email Address') ?>" />
```

But when I clicked on submit button without entering value then it considers example text means `"john@gmail.com"` as login id but it have to show error "required field.". Please help me.

Comment: why not use the placeholder attrib instead of setting the value ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why bother with javascript to do this, when you can just use built-in features of HTML5?
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_placeholder.asp

Here is a jsFiddle showing what I am talking about:

```
<form action="something.html" method="post">
    Please enter your login: <input type="text" id="loginTextBox" name="login[username]" placeholder="john@gmail.com" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/76PvF/

if you want to make the placeholder text go away when it gets input focus, you can do this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#loginTextBox")
        .focus(function(){
            //on focus, put placeholder into data and blank out the placeholder
            $(this).data("placeholder", $(this).attr("placeholder"));
            $(this).attr("placeholder", "");    
        })
    .blur(function(){
            //on blur, put the placeholder back
            $(this).attr("placeholder", $(this).data("placeholder"));
        });
});
```

updated jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/76PvF/1/

Comment: I can use placeholder but it doesn't hide text when I clicked on textbox.

Comment: see my update. If it fixes your problem, please pick it as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

you can use placeholder="john@gmail.com"

```
<input name="login[username]" placeholder"john@gmail.com" id="email" type="text" class="input-text required-entry" title="<?php echo $this->__('Email Address') ?>" />
```

Comment: Placeholder doesn't hide text after clicking on text. Please suggest me any other option